# Change barceloneta.css for Plone 5.02a?

Tags: css, themes, plone, plone-4.x

I want to be able to edit the Barceloneta Theme in Plone 5.02a.

One option: Copy the theme in the theming panel. However, the editing looks like this & the css files are missing.

[image: Edit Screen]

I saw that copying the barceloneta.css file is different then the bareloneta.css that loads with Plone 5.02a. Parts of Plone do not have css applied to them.

I thought about downloading the entire theme from github and editing it and using that. However, I got an error message when I tried this. This could be a possibility but I am probably doing it wrong.

My end goal in all of this is to get my plone 5.02a instance to look like the following:

[image: Final View]

Has anyone been able to alter the css for Plone 5.02a? I am aware of it's unreleased state as well.

Comment: can you post the error in uploading the zip? It can be useful for others. Also, you can open an issue in dev.plone.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the web theme editing is a known issue and is being worked on.

It's mostly a js rewrite of those widgets. You can track the progress, if you care, at https://github.com/plone/mockup/tree/vangheem-resourceeditor